# Multiple urls in single state with ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am developing a SPA service. I am very happy because of angular.js and ui-router.

I have tried implementing states with ui-router for angular.js 1.x. There is something question about this.

Here is my code snippets. There are 2 states for path `#/ant/holding` and `#/settings/holding`.

I thought this code which maybe can merged into one state. It is right? If I right, how to merge these states ?

I have tryed to search on google, but I didn't find. How can I implement a single state for multiple urls ?

```
$stateProvider.state('ant', {
    url : '/ant',
    templateUrl : "ant/view",
    controller : "AntController"
})
.state('ant.holding', { // holding stocks
    url : '/holding',
    templateUrl : "ant/holdStockList"
})
.state('settings', {
    url : '/settings',
    templateUrl : "more/view",
    controller : "MoreController"
})
.state('settings.holding', { // holding stocks
    url : '/holding',
    templateUrl : "ant/holdStockList"
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find information about [Nested routing](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views).

I assume you can use here `children` property, or `views`. Here is example with a children concept:

```
let holding = {
    url: '/holding',
    templateUrl: "ant/holdStockList"
};

$stateProvider.state('ant', {
    url: '/ant',
    templateUrl: "ant/view",
    controller: "AntController",
   children: [holding]
}).state('settings', {
    url: '/settings',
    templateUrl: "more/view",
    controller: "MoreController",
    children: [holding]
})
```